# Removing flush mounted ceiling fixture that has springs atached to it

Tags: light-fixture

I'm having problems removing a flush mounted ceiling fixture that seems to be attached to some sort of spring or springs.  Please advise the best way to remove the fixture so I can change the bulb.  A link to a video would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Steve. Welcome to the Home Improvement Stack Exchange. It would be very helpful in your quest for some answers if you could post a photo or two of your existing fixture...including evidence what you believe to be the "spring or springs".

Answer (score 1):

Trim rings for can fixtures (which are recessed, but look "flush" from below) are often spring-mounted. The ones I've met either have a pair of "long-legged" springs that go into a slot where they will release if you squeeze the legs together (the trim pulls down from the ceiling several inches and stops on bent-out ends of the springs) or two or three coil springs, where you usually have to unhook one end of the coil spring to release the trim (which is more of a pain.)

Either one can be awkward, so start by being on a secure, comfortable work platform, not precariously balanced on whatever is handy.